# Pythn 3.6 f-string on pre-formatted string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format, f-string

How can I re-format using f-string this **string**:

```
string_from_db = "Hello {full_name}"
full_name = "Mark X"
return f'{string_from_db}'
```

This example is not working, I have a string which is ready for params injections in the DB, And I want to use python 3.6 f-string on that data.

Thank you

Comment: You can't. Use `.format`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a similar pre f-string approach:

```
def my_function():
    string_from_db = "Hello {full_name}"

    full_name = "Mark X"

    return string_from_db.format(**locals())

print(my_function())
```

Or a more standard approach:

```
def my_function():
    string_from_db = "Hello {full_name}"

    full_name = "Mark X"

    return string_from_db.format(full_name=full_name)

print(my_function())
```